# Gradle Failed to resolve my custom library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, jcenter

I have used the following guide to upload my custom library to jcenter : https://ptyagicodecamp.github.io/how-did-i-publish-android-library-to-jcenter-from-android-studio.html

but it shows failed to resolve mylibrary:mylib:v1, when i just use the aar file it works fine so i know there no issue with library itself, can anyone help me, what am i missing i can't understand its my first time working with libraries so sorry for this question.

Comment: same issue. Have you found solution?